# Add border on row in grid with border-collapse: separate

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, devextreme-angular

I developed a data grid. I intend that the rows on that grid are separate, so I used border-collapse: separate.

My problem is that using this I can't add a border to the line.

Is there a way to add border to the row and keep the table rows separate?

[Example - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qay2gw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

```
<dx-data-grid style="margin-top:50px" class="tableTask" [dataSource]="datas"
    [showColumnLines]="false" [showRowLines]="false" [columnAutoWidth]="true" [allowColumnResizing]="true">
    <dxo-header-filter [visible]="true"></dxo-header-filter>
    <dxi-column dataField="ID" dataType="text" caption="ID"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Name" dataType="text" caption="Name"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

**css**

```
::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-headers  {
letter-spacing: 0;
color: #4D4F5C !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
font-size: 13px !important;
background-color:#EDF3F9;
    -ms-touch-action: pinch-zoom;
    touch-action: pinch-zoom;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
  border-radius: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
}

::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 60px;
}

::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-headers + .dx-datagrid-rowsview {
   border-top: 0 !important;
}

::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-content .dx-datagrid-table {
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  border-spacing: 0px 16px !important;
}

::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-headers .dx-datagrid-table .dx-row > td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want keep using `border-collapse: separate`.

You can simply add **border** to each **td** of each **row** :

```
::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Add the code above at the end of your **CSS**.

And if you want to add a full border to your row you can use this :

```
::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
} 
::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid red !important;
}
::ng-deep .tableTask .dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-row td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

I have added `!important` to border-left because there's already some CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult as you can't add border to the `tr` of a table.

You could try to use pseudolement `:after` to render a line for the table row but now the problem is:

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

So you could try the "hack" to add `transform: scale(1);` to your rows to make it work. Like this:

```css
table {border-collapse:separate;border-spacing: 10px;}
td {}
tr {position:relative;transform: scale(1);}
tr:after  {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:1px;
  background-color:#000;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>dasdasd</td>
    <td>dasda</td>
    <td>asdasda</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dasdasd</td>
    <td>dasda</td>
    <td>asdasda</td>
  </tr> <tr>
    <td>dasdasd</td>
    <td>dasda</td>
    <td>asdasda</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, I will never recomend the use of css hacks on any web.